# How to enable terminal beeping?

Tags: python, term, ansi-term, warning, error

xterm conviniently beeps on a failed unit test (pytest):

**Beeping**

`(start-process "" nil "/usr/bin/xterm" "-e" "python3" "-B" "-m" "pytest_watch" "--clear" "--" "-s" "--last-failed")`

Now I need this beep in `term` or `ansi-term`. How can can I do this?

**Not yet beeping**:

```
(switch-to-buffer (make-term "test-term" "/bin/bash" nil "-c" "python3 -B -m pytest_watch --clear -- -s --last-failed"))
(switch-to-buffer (term-ansi-make-term "test-ansi" "/bin/bash" nil "-c" "python3 -B -m pytest_watch --clear -- -s --last-failed"))
```

Comment: You might be able to use the Emacs function `ding`...

Answer (score 1):

pytest tells the terminal to beep by printing a BEL character, ascii 0x07. Emacs `term` looks for the same character and calls `ding` to ring the bell.

The way `ding` works is by looking at the variable `ring-bell-function`. If it is non–nil, it calls this function. However, the default value for this variable is `ignore`. This is a function that doesn’t do much, so generally Emacs is silent. If the variable is nil, then it falls back to an OS–specific hook which may or may not do anything. On Linux, with X Windows, this is done by calling XkbBell (or XBell, in the unlikley case that you built Emacs without Xkb). Very likely that will be handled by your desktop environment, which should allow you to customize the sound that plays.

Or you could set it to a function of your own that plays a sound by some other means, such as by running an appropriate sound–playing program on a sound file of your choosing.